# setSelectionRange moves the cursor, doesn't select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-input

I have made a jsFiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/31mts93v/

I want to create an input box that functions in this way:  When you press left and right arrow keys, it selects (as in a mouse select) the previous word or next word depending on where the cursor is.

To start this off, I need to be able to dynamically select a part of the text when you press the left arrow key.  Although It just seems to move the cursor and nothing is selected, as in the above jsFiddle.

The HTML is:

`<input type='text' id='humantext' class='form-control' value='foo bar and bar bar foo, a bar fooey foo foo bar' />`

The JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function createSelection(start, end) {
    var field = document.getElementById('humantext');
    console.log(start + ' ' + end);
    if( field.createTextRange ) {
        console.log('createtextrange');
        var selRange = field.createTextRange();
        selRange.collapse(true);
        selRange.moveStart('character', start);
        selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
        selRange.select();
    } else if( field.setSelectionRange ) {
        console.log('setSelectionRange');
        field.focus();
        field.setSelectionRange(2, 7);
    } else if( field.selectionStart ) {
        console.log('selectionStart');
        field.selectionStart = start;
        field.selectionEnd = end;
    }
    field.focus();
}     

$("#humantext").keydown(function (e) {
    var words = $(this).val().split(' ');
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        // Left Arrow
        createSelection(0,5);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        // Right Arrow
        createSelection(10,20);

    }
});
});
```

**Second Edit** After an entire morning, I finally managed it.  My big hangup was not preventing default when pressing an arrow key.  here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/31mts93v/3/

Comment: 3rd different question today on same problem?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not getting anywhere with it.  And I worded it completly wrong in the last question, and this time i have a jsFiddle to prove it! :)

Comment: Tried but got to where you are now :)

Comment: @JoakimM I created a button, and attached a setSelectRange to that and it worked fine.  So it seems that it wont execute correctly when its fired from `keydown` or `keypress`.  I can't work out why.

Comment: @JoakimM I managed it! http://jsfiddle.net/31mts93v/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things that need to be done:

- Add `event.preventDefault()`
- Use start and end variables instead of hard coded 2 & 7
- Right arrow keyCode is 39

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function createSelection(start, end) {
    var field = document.getElementById('humantext');
    console.log(start + ' ' + end);
    if( field.createTextRange ) {
        console.log('createtextrange');
        var selRange = field.createTextRange();
        selRange.collapse(true);
        selRange.moveStart('character', start);
        selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
        selRange.select();
    } else if( field.setSelectionRange ) {
        console.log('setSelectionRange');
        field.focus();
        field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if( field.selectionStart ) {
        console.log('selectionStart');
        field.selectionStart = start;
        field.selectionEnd = end;
    }
    field.focus();
}     

$("#humantext").keydown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var words = $(this).val().split(' ');
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        // Left Arrow
        createSelection(0,5);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        // Right Arrow
        createSelection(10,20);

    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omahlama/pszwmomk/1/

Comment: @OliM Thanks!!! Yes the hardcoded numbers were just me testing.  That works well, I can't believe I forgot about `preventDefault()`, of course, it makes so much sense.  Thank you!!